# Traceroute to just one domain

Tags: traceroute

Traceroute showing all *** for ONLY ONE DOMAIN. Why? Server has checked to see if it my IP is blocked and it is not. I manage the site and none of it works, email, FTP, cpanel, website, NADA.

What now?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons. The "simplest" explanation is that the host doesn't respond to ICMP requests. Another reason could be that it's overloaded and other protocols are taking precedence over replies to ICMP.

If you receive replies from hosts after it, the issue is less likely to be network related.

Comment: `traceroute` normally uses UDP, not ICMP. Some versions of `traceroute` have an option to use ICMP and a minority of variants use ICMP by default.